# Get legend right with stacked bar plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to generate a plot which contains both lines (`plot`, `stairs`) and bars (`bar`). For `plot` and `stairs`, I usually use `'DisplayName'` property to generate the legend. With a stacked `bar` plot, this does not seem to work anymore. Consider this MWE:

```
x_max = 20;
results = [3 37 50; 7 27 25; 11 0 13; 18 45 0];
figure('Position', [470 430 1000 600]);
plot(0:x_max, polyval([3 1], 0:x_max), 'DisplayName', 'Production rate');
hold on; grid on;
bh = bar(results(:,1), results(:,2:3), 0.2, 'stacked', 'DisplayName', 'Fraction');
xlim([0 x_max]);
legend('Location', 'best');
set(gca, 'FontSize', 18);
hold off
```

Which produces this plot:
[image]

I would like to get a custom legend entry for each of the two fractions, e.g., `'Fraction1', 'Fraction2'`. However, both variantes produce an error:

```
bar(results(:,1), results(:,2:3), 0.2, 'stacked', 'DisplayName', 'Fraction1', 'Fraction2')
bar(results(:,1), results(:,2:3), 0.2, 'stacked', 'DisplayName', {'Fraction1', 'Fraction2'})

>>Error setting property 'DisplayName' of class 'Bar':
Value must be a character vector or string scalar.
```

But if I do

```
bh.get('DisplayName')
```

I get

```
ans =

  2×1 cell array

    {'getcolumn(Fraction,1)'}
    {'getcolumn(Fraction,2)'}
```

Which means that Matlab internally does generate a cell array for the `'DisplayName'`, but does not let me assign one. This fails:

```
bh.set('DisplayName', {'Fraction1'; 'Fraction2'})
```

I know I could edit the cell array of legend entries directly, but I prefer the `'DisplayName'`, since the legend entries never get out of order when I change the plot commands (or add or delete any of them). Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a quick workaround, you could set each bar object's `DisplayName` after creation.
See this solution which builds on your example:

The issue you're having is that the stacked `bar` creates a `Bar` array (in this case 1x2). You can't set the `DisplayName` property of the `Bar` array, you need to set the property of each `Bar` *in* the array.

```
% Your example code, without trying to set bar display names
x_max = 20;
results = [3 37 50; 7 27 25; 11 0 13; 18 45 0];
figure('Position', [470 430 1000 600]);
plot(0:x_max, polyval([3 1], 0:x_max), 'DisplayName', 'Production rate');
hold on; grid on;
bh = bar(results(:,1), results(:,2:3), 0.2, 'stacked');
xlim([0 x_max]);
legend('Location', 'best');
set(gca, 'FontSize', 18);
hold off

% Set bar names
names = {'Fraction1'; 'Fraction2'};
for n = 1:numel(names)
    set( bh(n), 'DisplayName', names{n} );
end
```

You can do this without the loop, at the cost of slightly less explicit syntax:

```
names = {'Fraction1'; 'Fraction2'};
[bh(:).DisplayName] = names{:};
```

[image: plot]